# Live Paypal Application fails to create token information from auth code but not in sandbox

Tags: node.js, rest, api, paypal, authorization

In my Meteor web application I have managed to successfully implement some functions that allow me to take an authorization code granted from Paypal's authorizeUrl function via the RESTful Paypal Node SDK in the Sandbox in order to assign a refresh token to an existing user. However, now that we need to deploy it to a Live environment, we are running into problems because the Paypal API is complaining with the following error:

`Error: Response Status: 400`

This means the request was bad, due perhaps to a 'bad syntax.' However, I am using the correct live API credentials and the authorization URL endpoint is the correct one at https://www.paypal.com/signin/authorize

Unfortunately this bug doesn't occur when I am reverting back to my sandbox mode configuration.

As a follow up, trying to pass an invalid authorization code to my sandbox configuration endpoint provides me the appropriate error message 400 with `Invalid authorization code` whereas the live environment gives me no such help...

The latest `paypal-debug-id` I have on hand is `83d570f17357e`

EDIT:

It turns out Paypal thinks `client id or secret is null` even though I have clearly provided the configuration with client_id, client_secret, openid_client_id and openid_client_secret. This confuses me even more

EDIT 2:

Using the same Live API credentials I can successfully set up a basic payment flow using the Rest SDK, but I cannot use open ID connect with the same client ID and secret. Maybe that has something to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

After some extensive testing and wrestling with the API it was discovered that there was actually a configuration conflict going on when binding the Meteor.wrapAsync API call to an instance of paypal created from the node SDK.

Assuming my Meteor.wrapAsync call is this:

```
var wrapGetUserInfo = Meteor.wrapAsync(openIdCxn.userinfo.get.bind(openIdCxn.userinfo), function (err, userinfo) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        throw new Meteor.Error(500, "Internal Server Error", err);
    }
});
```

Then instead of doing

`var userInfo = wrapGetUserInfo(returnObject.access_token, paypal);`

I will do

`var userInfo = wrapGetUserInfo(returnObject.access_token);`

And then it no longer complains